# debugging with IIS 10.0

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am developing an asp.net page that works with large arrays. The site is running on IIS 10.0.
In the config file, there is this code:
`<runtime>`
`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true"/>`
`</runtime>`
On the asp.net page this is the first line:
`<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>`
There is an array that measures 30K by 30K.
If debug is set to false, the code executes. However, if debug is set to true, the out-of-memory message appears.
Why would this happen?

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/442448 words from the creator of ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog post from Microsoft from 2006:
https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/442448
It states that for asp.net pages, debug should be set to false.

Comment: The actual useful pieces of that blog post for your case are 1-3 under "Doing so causes a number of non-optimal things to happen including". Anyway, feel free to accept your own answer.